Adding Vendors (AP30300) as an Entity Type on the Approval Maps Screen
Does anyone have experience adding additional entities to the approval maps screen? I created a custom workflow for the Vendors screen, but I am unable to set up an approval map, as it does not exist for Vendors.


Any help or advice is much appreciated!
